# Cobra/Lobo Dead?

Tags: lobo-cobra

Are the Cobra and Lobo projects dead?

http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp
http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp

A.

Answer (score 0):

Their SourceForge project hasn't been updated since January 2009.  I'd guess yes... which is a pity.  It'd be really handy right about now as a java replacement for part of wkhtmltopdf.